# Simple weather app didn't work?

Tags: java, android, json

I am trying to display main and description from json data i take from opneweathermap. And nothing happen, but I don't have errors.

I will not include the link.

Here is my MainActivity  class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button mButton;
    private TextView mTextView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

        mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                DownloadTask task = new DownloadTask();
                task.execute("Link");
            }
        });
    }


    public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

            String result = "";
            URL url;
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

            try {
                url = new URL(urls[0]);

                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

                InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);

                int data = inputStreamReader.read();

                while(data != -1){

                    char current = (char) data;

                    result+=current;

                    data = inputStreamReader.read();

                }

                return result;

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            try {

                String message = "";

                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);

                String weatherInfo = jsonObject.getString("weather");

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Soem"+message,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                Log.i("Weather content", weatherInfo);

                JSONArray array = new JSONArray(weatherInfo);

                for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++){

                    JSONObject jsonPart =  array.getJSONObject(i);

                    String main = "";
                    String description = "";

                    main = jsonPart.getString("main");
                    description = jsonPart.getString("description");

                    if(main != "" && description != ""){

                        message += main + ": " + description + "\r\n";

                    }
                }

                if(message != ""){
                    mTextView.setText(message);
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have included uses-permissions and i have TextView and Button that will display the  data from json in my layout file.

Comment: How does the received data look?

Comment: From the link or ?

Comment: Its unclear what you want to do. You wrote: "from opneweathermap". So what does the data look like you get from this source? How do you store it? How do you want to show it on your app?

Comment: Ok so here is the link of the web site i take the data: https://openweathermap.org/

Comment: And? Do you get data?

Comment: This is how ti looks: https://postimg.org/image/qs8x9prwn/

Comment: All i want is to take main and description from weather and display it in TextView

Comment: u dont answer my question: Do you receive data? If you have received the data you posted above then your problem seems to be showing it in your textview.

Comment: - Did I received data?
--> Print it out in the console.
Does the textview show up?
-->Try it with setText("Test");
if both works: textview.setText(receivedData.toString());
--> problem solved

Comment: urlconnecton.setRequestMethod("GET");urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json"); and try to print urlConnection.getResponseCode() and urlConnection.getResponseMessage() before while loop .Give these details